# Control GameObject renderer Order If the same type

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, shader, rendering

I'm trying to make a shader that the behavior is like the foods um imagem below.

[image: Example Image]

The foods are rendered entire in front of other even if some polygon are behind. The order of the render is defined by the touch. The last touched are rendered in front. Probably controled by script.

But, to render the water, the z-test are being used.

I had tried to put Z-test off and control using code, but the Object are rendered in front of everything.

I want that the Objects Food be rendered entire in front of other and control the order by code. But the interaction of that object with any other object respect z order normally.